# Websphere commerce authenticate property in struts redirecting to LogonForm

Tags: struts2, websphere, websphere-7

In WebSphere commerce, when I try to call a command which has authenticate property set to 1, it is redirecting to LogonForm URL when the user is not logged in.

For example, I am calling the below URL in a new browser without logging in

https://localhost/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TrackOrderStatus?catalogId=10201&langId=44&storeId=10151

and it has the struts entries defined in action-mappings section with the authenticate property set to 1.

I believe this will actually check whether the user is logged in, and if its not, it will give us the LogonForm URL as below

https://localhost/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/LogonForm?catalogId=10201&langId=44&storeId=10151

I wanted to know how this redirection is happening at IBM commerce level. This is because I want to change the LogonForm redirect URL to some third party URL (ex: ThirdPartyAuthController?catalogId=10201&langId=44&storeId=10151). Since this is happening internally, I am not sure how I can achieve this.

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: It's using a servlet response to send redirect. It's unclear what are you asking. Clarify the question, add details, without it the question is off-topic.

Comment: I need to know how it is redirecting because I wanted to change the redirect LogonForm URL to some third party authentication URL(ex: ThirdPartyAuthController?langId=44&catalogId=10201&storeId=10151) URL. Since this is happening internally, I am not sure how I can change this.

Comment: I think I found the answer in the below article

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0907_callaghan/0907_callaghan.html

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in the below link

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0907_callaghan/0907_callaghan.html